# rails: checking which controller method was called from within the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to check which controller method was called from within the model?

Example:
Say the controller create method was called:

```
def create
     do something
end
```

Then in the model do something only when create in the controller was called

```
if create?
      do something
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine you could examine the call stack but this is exactly what models are **not** for: they should now nothing about the controller.

Examining the stack:

```
if caller.grep /create/
  # do something
elsif caller.grep /update/
  #do something else
end
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: this is a special case. sometimes you need to see what method it came from. for instance in the validation methods there an :on => :create symbol

Comment: In that case just use the `caller` method that returns an array of method names called.

Comment: On the one hand it is nice to know something like this is possible. But this feels wrong to me like @Jakub said: this is not what models are for. And a model can know if you are creating a new object or updating an existing object. If there is a need for this, i would add a parameters to my initialize or something. To keep the model as ignorant and seperate as possible (not to mention testable: how will you test such behaviour?).

Comment: what if there's a method called `create` or `update` in the call stack other than the controller method?

Comment: @Alex well then you should just adjust the code. I provided this more as an example of how to do it. The `caller` method gives also file names so you could check that the method originated from the right file for example. And as I said, you shouldn't be doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a `create` flag to the model method, or make two different methods in the model and call the appropriate one from the controller. Otherwise you are creating a rather unpleasant dependency between the controller and the model. As you noted, validation methods take a parameter to specify when they are run.

Answer (score 2):

Check

```
if params[:action] == 'create'
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your model you can ask/know if the record you are handling is a new record or not

```
p = Post.new
p.new_record? => true
p = Post.first
p.new_record? => false
```

maybe that helps you enough?

Otherwise inside a model you can add [callbacks](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), e.g.  a `before_create` that is only called before a new record is saved. To keep your model lean, and you should have a lot of callbacks, those could be grouped inside an [observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html).

Hope this helps.